# QT 5.14 и Android - ошибка: инструменты SDK установлены

Tags: android, qt, sdk

Операционка: Windows 7.
Java: 1.8.0_241

Установил QT 5.14.2., выполнил инструкцию как тут сказано:
https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.14/android-getting-started.html

Ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Платформы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Инструменты сборки Android SDK:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Инструменты Android SDK:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В инструментах Android SDK необходимо доставить "Android SDK Tools (Obsolete) 26.1.1":

[image: Android SDK Tools (Obsolete) 26.1.1]

Comment: В wind'е их нет.

Answer (score 0):

Redbull правильно написал, эта настройка скрыта за галкой "Hide Obsolete Packages".
Я тоже сразу не заметил ;)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все заработало:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]